# Microsoft Graph API from microsoft streams app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As I have seen we can access the content of one drive and teams from Microsoft Graph api. Similarly, do there any Microsoft Graph API'S available to access content/videos uplaod by the user in Microsoft Streams.

Referred Doc :-

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/streamnew/new-stream

Comment: I'd love to see an update. Could the Microsoft Graph File API `Resumable Upload` be used to upload the raw video - then we'd need some way to kick-off an encoding session.  Or could we upload it to Blob Storage and then flag it as an Asset?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, its not available in the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/?search=streams), as its in the development and it's updated in the [Developer Roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?rtc=1&searchterms=54786&filters=In%20development&searchterms=teams%2Cstream). So you may need to watch the space.